# How can I securely store Gmail SMTP credentials in a Unity project to comply with security guidelines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity Asset that sends emails via Gmail's SMTP server. The submission was rejected due to insecure storage of email credentials. Here's the problem:

Email credentials (including the App Password) are stored directly in the Unity project.
Unity suggested finding alternative solutions without specifics.
Code snippet causing the issue:

```
[SerializeField] private string ReceiverMail = "ReceiverMail@gmail.com";
[SerializeField] private string SenderMail = "SenderMail@gmail.com";
[SerializeField] private string appPassword = "SenderMailAppPassword(dfkfjjfkjgmnfk)";

private async void SendMail()
{
    // Code using email credentials...
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderMail, appPassword) as ICredentialsByHost;
    // More code...
}
```

Seeking advice on securely storing email credentials to prevent exposure in the built project.

[Detailed Explaination](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/210432/how-can-i-securely-store-gmail-smtp-credentials-in-a-unity-project-to-comply-wit)  (I couldn't post full details here as stackover flow was marking it spam for unknown reasons)

Comment: You could try securestring, but i dunno if that works with unity

Comment: Make a service with public endpoint which will authenticate preregistered user, OAuth will do. A service can send emails, push them in queue or do whatever it wants.